# Can the UWP applications scan the disk?

Tags: uwp, data-recovery, desktop-bridge, desktop-app-converter

As shown in title. we know that the data recovery applications would scan the disk and get information about disk partitions, but in UWP, the access to file system is limited, as the link descriped https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions
so, is it possible to convert the data recovery software to UWP through the Microsoft's [Desktop App Converter](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=51691) application.

Comment: For file recovery you generally need raw access to the storage, I doubt UWP provides that (imagine all the bad things you can do!). Also converting a win32 program to UWP is useless as it removes cross-platform ability. Might as well run the win32 app straight away...

Comment: You can answer this for yourself (just as I can): If you could convert a Windows Desktop application to a UWP application, retaining **all** functionality, why would Microsoft even bother to establish security firewalls for UWP apps? Everyone could easily circumvent them by converting a desktop application to UWP.

Comment: thanks all for your reply! but i want to know wheather there has some official resources by microsoft proved the impossibility of UWP for data recovery applications

Answer (score 0):

A Desktop Bridge application can access the file system with the full rights of the user that runs the app. This is unlike a pure UWP, which has additional restrictions enforced by the App Container sandbox.

There isn't enough detail in the original post to determine if this is sufficient for your software product, or if your process needs to run with admin or system privileges. This would not be supported, even for Desktop Bridge applications.

I would suggest you read the preparation guide for Desktop Bridge conversion to determine if this would be a good route for your PC software.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-prepare

Thanks,
Stefan Wick - Windows Developer Platform